# Why QRegExp matches this regular expression?

Tags: ipv4, qregexp

I found regular expression which should match IPv4 address:

```
QRegExp rx_ipv4("^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])$");
bool match = rx_ipv4.exactMatch("1.2.33333");
```

It returns true.

But in above regular expression part ending with dot must be repeated three times. What is wrong with this regular expression ?

Comment: The regexp seems to be fine based on [regexr](https://regexr.com/46qfi). Maybe QRegExp doesn't support some part of it or there's some other issue?

Comment: I tried it also with std::regex_match(). Result is the same. Is above regular expression right or is it bug in std ?

Answer (score 0):

Above regular expression is not right in C++ code.
C++ standard escape sequences does not contain: 
    '\.'

[C++ escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Right IPv4 regular expression in C++ is:

```
QRegExp rx_ipv4("^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\x2E){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$");
```

where \x2E is Ascii code for '.'